# getJSON with a domino view - not returning any data

Tags: json, knockout.js, lotus-domino

I am developing an application based on @TheoHeselmans presentation on using Knockoutjs to web enable Domino apps.

I am stuck on one bit.

I am trying to display a Domino view on the web page using the following code

```
    self.mainclient.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        $.getJSON('../api/data/collections/name/json', function(data) {
        var mappedClients = $.map(data, function(item) { return new ClientRow(item); });
        self.renewals(mappedClients);
        });
    }
);

function ClientRow(data) {
    this.Status = ko.observable(data.Status);
}
```

It does not return any data - or display an error but I see on the Domino console that the servlet is started.

I am setting the observable elements as follows:

```
self.renewals = ko.observableArray([]);
self.allclients = [{clientName: "ACME COMPANY"},{clientName: "GG Inc"}];
self.mainclient = ko.observable('');
```

mainclient gets set by selecting it from the drop-down list:

```
<select class="form-control" id="MainClient" data-bind="options: $root.allclients, value: mainclient, optionsText: 'clientName'">
</select>
```

Finally, the template variables are set as:

```
 <!-- Knockout JavaScript (+ mapping plug-in and bootbox lib)
================================================== -->
<script src="[DB]js/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="[DB]js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="[DB]js/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<!-- Templates -->

<script type="text/html" id="renewal-template">
          <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Status" /></td>
 </tr>
</script>

<script src="[DB]pages/ko_renewals.js"></script>
```

and the HTML that calls it as:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed"><tr class="warning"><th>Status</th></tr>
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: renewal-template', foreach: renewals }">
</tbody>
</table>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

The `<pre>` element returns nothing - even if it is placed inside the `<table>` or `<tbody>`. It does return values if placed inside the `<select>` elements.

The view I am trying to display is

[json view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFPwE.png)

Any help on what I have missed would be appreciated.

Thanks

Graeme

Comment: Have you tried to open the link in the browser? http[s]://<server>/<database>/api/data/collections/name/json  Do you have  "Domino Data Service" activated for server and database?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.

```
function Renewal(data) {
    this.Country = ko.observable(data.Country);
    this.Status = ko.observable(data.Status);
    this.updatelink = data['@link'] || '';
}

function AppViewModel() {
   var self = this;

   //create empty observable Array
   self.renewals = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.allclients = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.mainclient = ko.observable('');


   //Get list of Countries
   $.getJSON('../api/data/collections/name/(lookupclient)', function(data) {
        self.allclients(data[0].Client);
        self.mainclient(self.allclients[0]);
        }
   );

   //trigger an AJAX request to get tastings when the main country selection changes
   self.mainclient.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        $.getJSON('../api/data/collections/name/json?count=5&keys=' + newValue, function(data) {
        var mappedRenewals = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Renewal(item); });
        self.renewals(mappedRenewals);
        });
    });


}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

var vm = ko.dataFor(document.body); //for debugging
```